# Xamarin Android: C# Periodic Task (soft real-time)

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, task

I have extensively tried to search for this matter and could not reach any conclusion. I am using Xamarin with Visual Studio to design an app for Android in C# language. The app runs an async task which reads samples from the device microphone. So far there is no control of timing for this task. The code is as follows:

```
button.Click += async delegate
{
   //do some other stuff
   await read_mic_task();
}
```

The `read_mic_task()` is an `async Task` in which I read the samples from the microphone. I am measuring time between one and other execution using a Stopwatch and I can see the task runs with random periods. I would like to perform this task periodically and, despite searching a lot, I got nothing. Could you please give a help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)? This will allow you to implement a long-running background task which will continue to execute even though the user opens another application

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities if you also want to share it across platforms i would go with system threading timer. This timer can also be used in a portable class.

You can use it for example like:

```
private System.Threading.Timer _timer;

...

// setup timer with callback
_timer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimerTick);

// start timer: duetime = 0 when to first execute callback (0 = right now) and intervall 5s
_timer.Change(0, 5000);

...

// stop timer
_timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

...

private void OnTimerTick(object state)
{
    // do the intervall stuff here
}
```